# Constrain on parameters for Negative Log Likelihood Minimization

Tags: minimization, log-likelihood, iminuit, zfit

I am trying to fit a 5 parameter (a, b, c, d, e) model, where one of the parameters is constrained by another, let's say,

0< d < 1

e < |d|

**I am currently using [zfit](https://github.com/zfit/zfit) which as far as I know, uses [iMinuit](https://iminuit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**

I have only created the `zfit.Parameters` and put the limits such that the ranges accessible to them are valid, again, let's say:

`d = zfit.Parameter('d', value=0.5, lower_limit=0.3, upper_limit=1.0,  step_size=0.01)`

`e = zfit.Parameter('e', value=0.1, lower_limit=0.0, upper_limit=0.3, step_size=0.01)`

It has been working well so far, but I think it is not the right way to do it.

So my question is, what is the correct way to deal with this kind of constraint?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this limits with caution, as they block the variables, ideally, they should be far off the final value.

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

- either impose a constraint "mathematically" as a logical consequence, so define one parameter from another using a composed parameter (which is a function of other parameters). If possible, this should be the preferred way.
- Another option is to impose this restrictions in the likelihood with an additional term. This, however, can have repercussions as you modify the likelihood. The minimizer will find a minimum, but this is maybe not the minimum you have looked for. What you can use are SimpleConstraints and add a penalty term to the likelihood if any of the above is violated (e.g. `tf.cast(tf.greater(d, 1), tf.float64) * 100.`). Maybe make also sure that minuit is run with use_minuit_grad.

Comment: Hi! I've just tried the restriction option and I followed [this](https://zfit.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.3/intro/loss.html) to do it, however, I think it's outdated, so I look around and found the [upgrade guide](https://zfit.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.3/project/upgrade_guide.html) and added this code:

"""
def custom_constraint():

    return tf.cast(tf.greater(d, 1.), tf.float64) * 100.

dCon = zfit.constraint.SimpleConstraint(custom_constraint, [d])
nll.add_constraints(dCon)
"""
I just want to check if this is correct, and if there's a way to obtain the actual NLL from the loss obj?

Comment: Everything was answered in your pyHEP presentation, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I've forgot to mention but I've updated the docs regarding your point above, it was indeed outdated